# How to fit many activities in one

Tags: java, android, android-activity, timetable

I developing an android app - schedule for school. I should make a schedule for 50 forms in school. Main screen - activity with buttons which could transfer you to schedule of form.   1 form = 1 activity with TabWidget. Total - 50 activities. How I can do that in single activity?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please elaborate and add necessary code snippets

Comment: You can use 1 Activity with 50 fragments.

Comment: Fragments are the way to go.

Comment: @sonnv1368, how to show one of this fragments when user click on the button?

Comment: @SummerAugust: please read about fragment http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/08/android-fragment-example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use just one `Activity`. You don't need 50 activities or 50 fragments. You just have 50 different sets of data. This is a data problem, not a presentation problem.